# Jackson deserialize json string with "pseudo array" of objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to read data from this API https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

For this endpoint https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/.
I'm having issues mapping the data field to a POJO. The field really contains an array of objects but in terms of the json it's not really defined as an array.

i.e. instead of

```
data: [{"id":"1","name":"some object"},{"id":"5","name":"another object"},...]
```

the json has named fields like so

```
data: {"1":{"id":"1","name":"some object"},"5":{"id":"5","name":"another object"},...}
```

I can manually parse this using

```
objectMapper.readTree(new URL("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/"));
```

but is there a way automatically map these to a List?

Comment: It would be more natural to deserialise it to a `Map` from id to object.

Comment: I just visited that endpoint and it looks as though it is a list. (although the ticker doesn't -- which one are you interested in?)

Comment: @teppic I considered a Map but figure that i'm not interested in the key field, since i'm just going to iterate through the set and the id is already present within the json object.

Comment: @tgdavies, you're right i'm interested in the ticker endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse it into a map (as @teppic said) and then get the map values as a list.

To deserialize into a map, you can see the answer from this question: [Deserializing into a HashMap of custom objects with jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002132/deserializing-into-a-hashmap-of-custom-objects-with-jackson#18014407)

> ```
> TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
> MapType mapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, Theme.class);
> HashMap<String, Theme> map = mapper.readValue(json, mapType);
> ```

Assuming you have a class called `Item` with the `id` and `name` fields, you can do this:

```
String json = "{\"1\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"some object\"},\"5\":{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"another object\"}}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// create your map type <String, Item>
TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
MapType mapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, Item.class);
HashMap<String, Item> map = mapper.readValue(json, mapType);

// get the list
List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>(map.values());

System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[Item [id=1, name=some object], Item [id=2, name=another object]]
```

Your other option would be a custom deserializer, or reading the tree as you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

try this

String json = "[{\"name\":\"Steve\",\"lastname\":\"Jobs\"}]";
JsonArray jArray = (JsonArray)new JsonParser().parse(json);

String sName = jArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString());
String sLastName = jArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("lastname").getAsString());

see you later.