# How to convert a json string to java map

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I've a json string which must be converted as a *Java* map of `Long` and `Object`. When I tried with *Jackson* `ObjectMapper` it creates `LinkedHashMap` instances instead of `Object`

Json String

```
  "2": {
     "firstName": "test",
     "lastName": "test",
     "title": "test",
     "gender": "test",
        }
   }

Map<Long, Person> personMap = objectMapper.readValue(value, new TypeReference<Map<Long, Object>>(){});
```

I'm expecting a map of `long` and `Person` object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing into a HashMap of custom objects with jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002132/deserializing-into-a-hashmap-of-custom-objects-with-jackson). If you prefer `TypeReference`, use `new TypeReference<Map<Long, Person>>() {}`.